# How do I obtain Grand Duke/Duchess in Battle Chateau?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I obtained the rank of Duke rather quickly but I can't seem to get to the next level.

What are the requirements for obtaining Grand Duke/Duchess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Battle_Chateau#Ranks) your Title is determined by how many battles you've already won. An exception exists for the title of the Grand Duke/Dutchess for which you have to `defeat all Battle Chateau Trainers, excluding Gym Leaders, the Elite Four, and Diantha.`

According to the [German version of Bulbapedia](http://www.pokewiki.de/Kampfschloss) the titles are obtained at:

- Baron/Baroness - 0 Wins
- Viscount/Viscountess - 5 Wins
- Earl/Countess - 20 Wins
- Marquis/Marchioness - 40 Wins
- Duke/Duchess - 140 Wins
- Grand Duke/Grand Duchess - After defeating every trainer

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this will take me a while since I usually only battle the old people/kimono girls/gym leaders/elite 4.

Answer (score 0):

You have to defeat every trainer in Battle Chateau at least once.

Comment: Does that include Elite 4 members and Gym leaders?

Comment: No, according to Bulbapedia

Answer (score -2):

I didnt get promote to grand duke when I beat all trainer(I kept track of all trainers listed on bulbapedia). I quess you have to also beat certain amount of trainers to get the promotion.